# Qt/QML kernel version

Tags: android, c++, linux, qt, android-ndk

I am trying to compile a QML/C++ code example for Android. I compiled the code with no problem. When trying to run, it gives the error message:

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
Gen6+ requires Kernel 3.6 or later.
bubble: ../../../../../src/mesa/main/context.c:1501: _mesa_make_current: Assertion `newCtx->Version > 0' failed.
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

On ubuntu, to check the kernel version, I run the command on terminal:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-headers | grep ii
Linux kernel version 3.11.0
```

So, I am running the development host with Ubuntu on [version 3.11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Maintenance). On the other hand, I read that devices running on Android 4.2 are based on [Linux Kernel 2.6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29#Linux_kernel) - which in my case is the development target, a tablet Nexus 7.

Any suggestion what should it takes to get rid of this error?